# Change specific css styles through .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I am currently coding my personal [website](http://www.raphaellechner.com/demo/variety/) and could really need some help with the jQuery.

I wanted the sticky navigation to change it's background color once it passes the header section, for that I've used the jQuery WayPoint plugin.

Then I defined some special css for the content above and the content under the header section. So far the background and font color changes, the .active class link and the color of the .navbar-brand however doesn't change.

Is something wrong in the following script?

```
$navbar.find('.navbar-brand').animate({color:'white'},500);
            $navbrand.css({font-weight:"normal"});

$navbar.find('.navbar-brand').animate({color:'white'},500);
            $navbrand.css({font-weight:"normal"});
```

If yes, then I'd really appreciate a explanation why it is not working.

Here is the full code:

```
$('#navchange').waypoint(function() {
    var $navbar = $("#changenav");
    var $navbrand = $("active > a:focus");

    if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#navchange').css("top").replace("px", "")) {
        // Above
        $navbar.animate({backgroundColor:'transparent'},300);
        $navbar.find('a').animate({color:'white'},500);
        $navbar.find('.navbar-brand').animate({color:'white'},500);
        $navbrand.css({font-weight:"normal"});

    } else {
        $navbar.animate({backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'},500);
        $navbar.find('a:link').animate({color:'#1abc9c'},500);
        $navbar.find('.navbar-brand').animate({color:'#1abc9c'},500);
        $navbrand.css({font-weight:"bold"});

    }

});
```

And [here](http://www.raphaellechner.com/demo/variety/) is a link to my website.

Comment: You have a syntax error occurring. Care to share it with us? `$navbrand.css({font-weight:"normal"});` specifically should be giving you a syntax error. Press F12 to open your console.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you are missing a period before `active` in `var $navbrand = $("active > a:focus");`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

My syntax error is following: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , '

Comment: You haven't requested the bold version of the font from Google. Update the link for PT Sans Narrow to be `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors.

You should quote the css attributes in `.css`.

```
$navbrand.css({"font-weight":"normal"});
$navbrand.css({"font-weight":"bold"});
```

You are also missing a period in your `$navbrand` selector.

```
var $navbrand = $(".active > a:focus");
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I fixed the problem, but the font-weight:bold is still not working though. Any suggestions? 

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure why the `:focus` is used in your selector. Removing that might help.

Comment: Hm no that doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Try `console.dir($navbrand)` just before the bolding code. It may be that the `active` class is being applied after the selector variable is set.

Comment: You could also just use css to apply the bold style `.active > a { font-weight:bold; } .active:first-child > a { font-weight:normal; }`.

Comment: Yeah, but If I add it with CSS then it will be displayed at the header page as well. However my main problem is that the active style will be resetted once you scroll down and then up again. 

The console says following:
context: document
length: 0
prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
selector: ".active > a:focus"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51212/discussion-between-derek-s-and-user3558067)